# Explanation of the binomial theorem and the associated Big O notation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

I'm currently following the MIT Single Variable lectures online and the professor states that the binomial theorem for the expansion

$(x + \Delta x)^{n} = x^{n} + nx^{n-1}\Delta x + O((\Delta x)^{2})$

How is this derived, and what does the big O term of the expansion represent in terms of the binomial theorem. Just to put this in context, this expression was used when computing the derivative of $x^{n}$ using the limit definition.

Comment: That formula means that $$\frac{(x+\Delta x)^n - x^n - nx^{n-1} \Delta x}{\Delta x^2}$$
is bounded.

Comment: I actually found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/475999/3157) much more helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As njguliyev writes, it means that the quantity
$$\frac{(x+\Delta x)^n - (x^n + nx^{n-1} \Delta x)}{(\Delta x)^2}$$
is bounded, **for sufficiently small** $\Delta x$. That is, there exists an $M<\infty$ and an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $|\Delta x|<\epsilon$, we have
$$|(x+\Delta x)^n - (x^n + nx^{n-1} \Delta x)| <  M\,|(\Delta x)^2|.$$

The professor might have specified $\Delta x\to 0$ explicitly; if not, it was supposed to be implicit from the context.

Aside: Note that if $\Delta x$ is allowed to take arbitrarily large values, then the inequality cannot hold for any $M$. On the contrary, as $\Delta x\to\infty$ we get a different formula:
$$(x+\Delta x)^n=(\Delta x)^n+nx(\Delta x)^{n-1}+O\left((\Delta x)^{n-2}\right).$$